# How do I get my div class "one" to be on the left side of the page?

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to learn grid.  I am using grid areas and assigned my div class "two" appropriately as per css guidelines supposed to place elements as I had instructed it to "one two three" One being on the left side or margin of the page.  Unfortunately the elements are lining up directly beneath grid area two which is the center of the page.  Any instruction or pointers to obtain the goal would be great.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
family=Bangers&family=Bree+Serif&family=Chelsea+Market&family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap');
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-areas:
    "one two three"
    "one two three"
    "one two three";
grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 310px);
}

.title {
font-family: 'Chelsea Market', cursive;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
color: teal;
}

input[type="number"] {
width:40px;
}

.titles {
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

.pizza {
text-align: center;
color: tomato;
}


.one {

grid-area: one;
}

.two {
text-align: center;
grid-area: two;
color: tomato;
}

.three {

grid-area: three;
}

h2 {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

<div class="pizza">
                    <h3>Pizza by the slice ($2)</h3><br>
                    <input type="number" id="numSlice">
                </div>
                <div class="two">
                    <h3 class="two">Toppings</h3>
                    <p class="titles">Per Pepperoni($0.25):</p>  <input type="number" id="numPepp">
                    <p class="titles">Per Meatball($0.35):</p>  <input type="number" id="numMeat">
                    <p class="titles">Per Mushhroom($0.40):</p>  <input type="number" id="numMush">
                    <p class="titles">Per Olive($0.20):</p>  <input type="number" id="numOlives">
                </div>

                <div class="one">
                    <h3 class="one">Sides</h3>
                    <p class="titles">Potato Salad($1.25):</p>  <input type="number" id="numPSalad">
                    <p class="titles">Humus($2.50):</p>  <input type="number" id="numHumus">
                    <p class="titles">Caesar Salad($3.50):</p>  <input type="number" id="numCSalad">
                    <p class="titles">Garden Salad($2.25):</p>  <input type="number" id="numGSalad">

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following code snippet for the code change.

1. I have wrapped class `one` and class `two` with class `grid` `<div>`.
2. I have removed class `one` and class `two` from the `<h3>`
3. I have removed the `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
   family=Bangers&family=Bree+Serif&family=Chelsea+Market&family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap');` because there is error and causing the CSS not working.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one two three" "one two three" "one two three";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 310px);
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Chelsea Market', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: teal;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 40px;
}

.titles {
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

.pizza {
  text-align: center;
  color: tomato;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: two;
  color: tomato;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="pizza">
  <h3>Pizza by the slice ($2)</h3><br>
  <input type="number" id="numSlice">
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="two">
    <h3>Toppings</h3>
    <p class="titles">Per Pepperoni($0.25):</p> <input type="number" id="numPepp">
    <p class="titles">Per Meatball($0.35):</p> <input type="number" id="numMeat">
    <p class="titles">Per Mushhroom($0.40):</p> <input type="number" id="numMush">
    <p class="titles">Per Olive($0.20):</p> <input type="number" id="numOlives">
  </div>

  <div class="one">
    <h3>Sides</h3>
    <p class="titles">Potato Salad($1.25):</p> <input type="number" id="numPSalad">
    <p class="titles">Humus($2.50):</p> <input type="number" id="numHumus">
    <p class="titles">Caesar Salad($3.50):</p> <input type="number" id="numCSalad">
    <p class="titles">Garden Salad($2.25):</p> <input type="number" id="numGSalad">
  </div>
</div>
```